# Is "болгарка" a distorted transcription of burglar tool?

Tags: этимология

Or that tool came to the USSR from Bulgaria?

Comment: Here is a list of similar words: http://www.anekdot.ru/id/552880/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, first tool of such kind come to USSR from Bulgaria (Fortuna named, produced on "Элпром-Ловеч" plant now called Sparky)  - whey bought AEG licence in 1966.

Answer (score 2):

Second one, "tool came to the USSR from Bulgaria".

"Однако слово «болгарка» в обиходе российских людей появилось лишь в 70-х годах, когда начался массовый выпуск данного инструмента на "Болгарский завод "Элпром-Ловеч", и дальнейшие поставки на территорию СССР."